# How to round the decimal value which we store in the admin panel?

Tags: craft3

Is it possible to round the decimal value we store in the admin panel . Can anyone Explain me with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig offers various filters. So to round the decimal value, we can use a round filter.

The round filter rounds a number to a given precision:

```
{{ 42.55|round }}
{# outputs 43 #}

{{ 42.55|round(1, 'floor') }}
{# outputs 42.5 #}
```

The round filter takes two optional arguments; the first one specifies the precision (default is 0) and the second the rounding method (default is common)

- common rounds either up or down (rounds the value up to precision
  decimal places away from zero, when it is half way there – making 1.5
  into 2 and -1.5 into -2).
- ceil always rounds up.
- floor always rounds down.

For more filter in Craft CMS. You can check below link.
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html